# The filters navigation Only one unique filter per navigation is allowed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Getting Exception when using `.Include().ThenInclude().ThenInclude()` with condition to match exact values. Below is the sample query I am trying with.

```
public Task<TestModel> Test(int id)
        {
            return dbContext.Tables
                .Include(i => i.A).ThenInclude(s => s.AList.Where(c => c.id == 1).Take(1)).ThenInclude(c => c.B)
                .Include(i => i.A).ThenInclude(s => s.AList.Where(c => c.id == 2).Take(1)).ThenInclude(x => x.C)
                .Where(i => i.id == id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

Getting below error with this EF query.

```
InvalidOperationException: The filters 'navigation .Where(c => (int)c.id == 1) .Take(1)' and 'navigation .Where(c => (int)c.id == 2) .Take(1)' have both been configured on the same included navigation.
            Only one unique filter per navigation is allowed.For more information on including related data
```

I have to select data from specific table (B or C) based on condition. How can this query be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be that this would be best served by a projection rather than trying to filter domain models. Entities should always reflect a complete data state or a complete-able data state. (i.e. lazy load-able proxies) Loading entities in a partially complete state (some associated entities, but not all, and no fall-back to lazy load) can easily lead to confusion in the code when dealing with methods that accept entities as parameters. Are they getting a complete TableA, or a partially filled in one?

If this is data relevant to a particular View for example:

```
[Serializable]
public class ParticularTableAViewModel
{
    public int TableAId{ get; set; }
    public string FirstRelevantBName { get; set; }
    public string SecondRelevantBName { get; set; }
    public string SomethingFromFirstC { get; set; }
    public string SomethingFromSecondD { get; set; }
}
```

Then populating the view model via projection:

```
var viewModel = dbContext.TableAs
    .Where(a => a.Id == id)
    .Select(a => new ParticularTableAViewModel
    {
        TableAId = a.Id,
        FirstRelevantBName = a.TableABs
            .Where(ab => ab.bId == 1)
            .OrderBy(ab=>ab.CreatedAt)
            .Select(ab => ab.TableB.Name)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        SecondRelevantBName = a.TableABs
            .Where(ab => ab.bId == 2)
            .OrderBy(ab=>ab.CreatedAt)
            .Select(ab => ab.TableB.Name)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        SomethingFromFirstC = a.TableABs
            .Where(ab => ab.bId == 1)
            .OrderBy(ab=>ab.CreatedAt)
            .Select(ab => ab.TableB.TableC.Something),
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        SomethingFromSecondD = a.TableABs
            .Where(ab => ab.bId == 1)
            .OrderBy(ab=>ab.CreatedAt)
            .Select(ab => ab.TableB.TableD.Something)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

There are a number of assumptions to make from the example provided, but a few things to be cautious of:  When using methods like `FirstOrDefault` or `Take` you should always provide an `OrderBy` clause to ensure results are predictable & repeatable. The projected view model can flatten details like above or contain related view models to form a structure suitable for the view to iterate through. Avoid mixing view models and domain models though, such as creating a view model that contains properties that are set to Entities.  In situations where you want to pull back several complex details from entities prior to populating a view model you can opt for two passes, one to select an anonymous type with an applicable state to pull from into memory, then a second `Select` to build the view model. This can cut down on repeated filtering statements when pulling various related details. (Whatever ends up easier to read and understand down the road)

```
var data = await dbContext.TableAs
    .Where(a => a.Id == id)
    .Select(a => new 
    {
        TableAId = a.Id,
        FirstBDetails = a.TableABs
            .Where(ab => ab.bId == 1)
            .OrderBy(ab=>ab.CreatedAt)
            .Select(ab => new 
            {
                Name = ab.TableB.Name,
                SomethingFromC = ab.TableB.TableC.Something
            }).FirstOrDefault(),
        SecondBDetails = a.TableABs
            .Where(ab => ab.bId == 2)
            .OrderBy(ab=>ab.CreatedAt)
            .Select(ab => new 
            {
                Name = ab.TableB.Name,
                SomethingFromD = ab.TableB.TableD.Something
            }).FirstOrDefault(),
    }.SingleOrDefaultAsync();

if (data != null)
{
    return data.Select(x => new ParticularTableAViewModel
    {
        TableAId = x.TableAId,
        FirstRelevantBName = FirstBDetails.Name,
        SecondRelevantBName = SecondBDetails.Name,
        SomethingFromFirstC = FirstBDetails.SomethingFromC,
        SomethingFromSecondD = SecondBDetails.SomethingFromD
    }).Single();
}
```

Comment: This looks good if it is purely query, however, for update I would like to know a solution to load affected entities and then update it with new data !

Comment: When doing updates you should have the PK IDs of every applicable entity you want to update, so load them as needed. If you want to add/remove children or change associations then you need to eager load those sets/references.  This is done at the time of update, not at the time of read. Projection to VMs @ Read, Load entities/graphs  /w eager loading @ Update. The common trap is wanting to only read once, but you should read data at update to ensure the data had not changed since it was initially read. (I.e. RowVersion checks)